I need to see what my website looks like on Mac
I have designed a website and I have already been told the page doesn't display correctly on Safari. I need to be able to interactively test that - preferably without buying a mac.
My problem is even if I go to all the trouble of setting up a hackintosh or some VM trick to run safari on my PC, that will still have access to all my fonts. I need to see how my website looks when displayed on a Mac or a different PC.

If you run macOS in a VM, it most certainly won't have access to your host system's fonts. There are ways to get macOS running in a VM like this, though it's obviously not sanctioned by Apple. The only other options are to buy genuine hardware or to rent a VPS online (or an online browser-testing tool that specifically includes macOS).

You can run Safari on your PC anyway, without Hackintosh. And its normal, in your website code to tell the browser, the fonts and fallback fonts to use. I have never had the need to test my multiple websites on the Mac.

How are you running it?  Windows Safari stopped being produced in 2012.
